# In excel, how do i return text from a cell if part of that text is contained in another cell?

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Query]

I hope this makes sense.

The users in Column AG are AF's managers who will also have their own entry in column AF.

So, if for example an entry in Column AG is listed in Column AF, return **their** manager into a blank cell.

I imagine it will be an `IF` function but I cannot work it out.

Comment: Maybe add what you try, and as formatted code / table a more minimal sample for the data (maybe CSV?) and people will for sure come to help further. Thanks.

Comment: `I hope this makes sense` - it could make more sense if column headers were visible on the picture. Though even if they were, it would still be rather confusing what must be put where.

Comment: like: `=IFERROR(INDEX(AG:AG,MATCH(AG2,AF:AF,0)),"")` for AH2?